# MySQL Sorting by multiple columns with previous row ID

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a set of rows that looks like this:

[image]

I need to sort these rows, first based on the "SequenceNo". and then based on the "PreviousID". So that the final result should be something like this (the last 2 rows should be swapped):

[image]

I did an extensive search but couldn't really find something that fits this scenario. 
Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using order by and group by togheter?

Comment: Can you explain the logic for seqno1 sorting ascending and seqno 2 sorting descending?

Comment: Are you just looking for... `SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY SequenceNo, PreviousID` ?

Comment: @P.Salmon the sequence no. 2 should consider the "PreviousID" column which indicates the ID of the previous row. when PreviousID = 0, its the starting row, and then for the sequence no. 1 you can see the second row has the PreviousID as 201, which is correct. And then for the 3rd row it should have the sequence no. 2 and the Previous ID as 204 (ID of the 2nd row) so on and so forth.

Comment: @GMB No, the PreviousID column indicates the previous Row ID. so direct order by doesn't really work

Comment: I dont really understand why you would want to do that. Also, im not sure if something like this is possible in SQL. I guess that if you only want to swap the last rows, you should do it in whatever language you use to communicate with the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try self joining and sorting

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int,seqno int, previous_id int);
insert into t values (201,1,0),(204,1,201), (202,2,203),(203,2,204);

select t.id,t.seqno,t.previous_id , t1.id,t1.seqno,t1.previous_id 
from t
left join t t1 on t1.id = t.previous_id
order by t1.seqno,t1.id;

+------+-------+-------------+------+-------+-------------+
| id   | seqno | previous_id | id   | seqno | previous_id |
+------+-------+-------------+------+-------+-------------+
|  201 |     1 |           0 | NULL |  NULL |        NULL |
|  204 |     1 |         201 |  201 |     1 |           0 |
|  203 |     2 |         204 |  204 |     1 |         201 |
|  202 |     2 |         203 |  203 |     2 |         204 |
+------+-------+-------------+------+-------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Awesome! I can work with this. thanks a lot for the help mate. cheers!